# TeamCity CI failing to find NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, nuget

I'm configuring a TeamCity build server for .Net CI and I can't seem to get NuGet to work correctly.

So far I have done the following:

- enabled NuGet via the TeamCity administration page
- Enabled a NuGet build step
- Validated that the NuGet tab appears correctly on the build page *and shows the correct packages*

but I continue to get the following error:

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3bc6f7b8cc834839\.nuget\NuGet.targets(83, 9): Unable to locate 'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3bc6f7b8cc834839\.nuget\NuGet.exe'
```

I'm at a loss as my NuGet build step completes successfully, but my actual solution build does not as a result of it *not finding NuGet*

What have I missed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to include the nuget.exe from the .nuget folder in your source control.
If you edit the NuGet.target file the .nuget folder - which you probably did include in your source control, then'll see at about line 15 (so it was here on my machine):

```
<!-- Download NuGet.exe if it does not already exist -->
<DownloadNuGetExe Condition=" '$(DownloadNuGetExe)' == '' ">false</DownloadNuGetExe>
```

Change that to :

```
<!-- Download NuGet.exe if it does not already exist -->
<DownloadNuGetExe Condition=" '$(DownloadNuGetExe)' == '' ">true</DownloadNuGetExe>
```

And voila !

Michael

Answer (score 1):

That path is looking for nuget.exe in you repository's .nuget folder. do you have that included in your source control?

Comment: Of course not - git's default ignore list includes *.exe :-D

Comment: Seems like bad form to me to include the exe. See the answer below from @MMichael Bruyninckx for a more correct solution.